# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.automl.runtime._automl_forecast_freq' " while loading a model in azure

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-notebooks

I have executed "pip install azureml-automl-runtime" in azure notebook.
When I try to load the model with below code

model_path = "forecast/model.pkl"

loaded_model = pickle.load(open(model_path, 'rb'))

I have tried loaded_model = joblib.load(open(model_path, 'rb')) as well but same error is displayed.

then "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.automl.runtime._automl_forecast_freq' " error message is displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dec2b.png)

Answer (score 0):

replace existing library with the below library and retry

```
from azureml.automl.core.forecasting_parameters import ForecastingParameters
```

Make sure that the code is being executed in virtual environment not in root environment.

For further reference check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-auto-train-forecast) designed by [Larry Franks](https://github.com/Blackmist) and team

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.                                                                                                                              I have used this in my code as shown below , but still I am getting the error.                                                                               from azureml.automl.core.forecasting_parameters import ForecastingParameters

Comment: I have referred https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/python-sdk/tutorials/automl-with-azureml/forecasting-energy-demand/auto-ml-forecasting-energy-demand.ipynb (content#4)

Comment: Check the pickle file once whether it is executing in local with the same libraries or not. Once test and local. Update the result in comments to understand the situation.

Comment: I am using Azure notebook for execution. Can you please explain the meaning of virtual environment not in root environment. ?